# Can a form have more than one action?

Tags: php, forms, action, html-email

I have a form which at the minute is gathering the information and sending it to my database but I also want that information sent to an email address, which means i would need another form action call, is this possible?
So i have

```
<form action="fitting.php" method="post" target="myIframe">
```

And i need this on the same form

```
<form action="MAILTO:someone@example.com" method="post">
```

I dont now if this is possible but would appreciate any help.

Comment: Just put `mail()` (or your `mailto:`) after your (*successful*) query, why two forms? Hit two posts with one stone ;-)

Comment: Its just the one form but i want same info sent to database and sent to an email.

Comment: @Fred-ii- `mailto` opens your favorite mail client.

Comment: [`Refer to comment #1`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22966146/can-a-form-have-more-than-one-action#comment35066782_22966146)

Comment: OP can still achieve it the same thing @Jurik Query success, mailto; done.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I just want say that he maybe want something else than we expect.

Comment: Sounds "cut & dried" to me @Jurik

Answer (score 0):

No, the action attribute is at the form level. You'll need to [send the email from your PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) script, which is perhaps desirable anyway.

Look out for scripts using your form, however. You may want to do one of those "Prove you are human... what is a+b? things:

```
$right_answer = $_SESSION['human_prompt_answer'];
if($_POST['human_prompt_answer'] == $right_answer) {
  mail($to, $subject, $message);
}
```

Then when building the form:

```
$a = rand(0,10);
$b = rand(0,10);
$_SESSION['human_prompt_answer'] = $a+b;

// ... then in your HTML:
<label>What is <?php echo $a;?> + <?php echo $b;?>?</label>
<input type="text" name="human_prompt_answer" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Form:

```
<form action="fitting.php" method="post" target="myIframe">
    <!-- inputs and stuff -->
</form>
```

fitting.php:

```
<?php
    // send to database with mysqli, PDO or framework methods
    // ...
    mail($to, $subject, $message);
?>
```